# How to highlight background in Visual studio for Obsolete class instances using DiagnosticAnalyzer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis, obsolete

A class is marked as Obsolete and I don't want the build to fail so it is only marked as a warning.

But to discourage developers to use this class in future, I want to highlight background or change the colour to bright RED wherever it is being used in Visual Studio designer.

Is it possible to do this using **DiagnosticAnalyzer**.